# Nginx and Docker - expose localhost port 8000 to localhost port 80

Tags: docker, web, nginx, server

I've got a docker container presenting a web app on localhost:8000.

I'd like to add a separate Nginx docker container as a reverse proxy to present the web app on localhost:80 which I will open up for access from the wider internet.

However, running: `docker run --name nginx -p 80:8000 --rm nginx` exposes port 8000 within the nginx docker container to localhost:80.

How would I expose `localhost:8000` on the host machine (which is running my web app) through the nginx container to `localhost:80`, also on my host machine?

Many thanks,
Robin

Comment: why do you want to run a separate container?

Comment: Because that is a best practice when dockerizing services. It leads to better manageability and better scalability.

Comment: For nginx, you'd just want -p 80:80  You would need to configure nginix to forward traffic to your app container on 8000.  You should use docker compose or docker swarm since you need the two containers to exist on the same internal network.  I would recommend swarm over compose at this point.

Comment: Thanks very much for the responses - having read around docker swarm and docker compose, I know these are the tools I need to make it happen. Much appreciated for your time and knowledge.